# HelpPage for Web Api using OData not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm using the default MVC Help Page for a Web API that uses OData, it works great but if I inherit ODataController instead of ApiController then the Help Page doesn't generate. It shows blank. Only classes that inherit from ApiController show up on the Help Page.

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
```

works fine and generates in the Help Page

```
public class BaseApiController : ODataController
```

doesn't generate a Help Page even though ODataController inherets from ApiController

Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how you do it. It's really easy, but its also dangerous! You will probably NOT want to do this after you see it for yourself.

1. In your AppStart\ODataConfig.cs file, make sure the route prefix is set to whatever your prefix is in AppStart\WebApiConfig.cs.  In most cases, it is api.

   example: config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "api", model);
2. Then add this line to each controller that implements
   ODataController that you want to show in the help.
   [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]

---

That's it really. The popular HelpPage plugin relies on IApiExplorer which observes the decorator.  The OdataController abstract class has this decorator set with (IgnoreApi = true).

If you also use the 'Test Button' plugin, it may not work as you expect if you're new to odata, but you can ignore the default stuff and place a proper odata query in there and execute it.

Now the part that really sucks is that you seem to lose odata navigation if your odata config and regular api config share the same prefix. So given that the odata conventional procedures displayed by the help page are not directly consumable, and in order to preserve navigation the indicated prefix would be wrong, it is not worth leaving this in a production app.

What I would do, is put a link to the meta data in the help page View.

Now if we can get someone at Microsoft to Open Source this or update it for odata controllers, that would be great.

Comment: What do you mean by "lose odata navigation" ? Having added the annotation, I still can use my browser and 'navigate' to the controllers methods, either API or OData, if that's what you mean.

Comment: This post is a bit stale and I don't quite remember, but I probably meant you lose $expand functionality if your Odata and WebApi prefixes are the same.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. HelpPage is intentionally *not* supported for OData based controllers.

Comment: Ah ok, Thank you. That's unfortunate. I mean my controller is part of the API but happens to also support OData. Any way around this?

Comment: OData controllers expose `$metadata` which is kind of a helppage for that protocol so it didn't make sense to have support for it on HelpPage

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense, but it would be nice if there was at least a away to automaticly list the available end points.

Answer (score 0):

Оf course you can show the controller and the method on the help page just put an attribute:

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]
```

You can even show what returns your method to this attribute:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(...))]
```